# SwiftUI - Hiding navigation bar during certain conditions

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

Is it possible to show/hide navigation bar on the view while the view is open, but during certain conditions I wish to show navigation bar and during other conditions I wish to hide it.

Let's say when I open the view, I wish to show navigation bar with title, but when an event gets canceled, I display a message on the view and during this point I wish to hide the nav bar. For this I am creating a state var "hideNavBar" which I initially set to false and then when an event is canceled i.e. view model's state changes to 'eventCanceled', in my view I am updating state variable's value to true. When "hideNavBar" is set to true, I see navigation bar hiding from the view, but when I set it to false again in onDisappear() I don't see navigation bar.

My entire app has one Navigation View which is in my app file. ContentView() in my app file opens all the other views, so entire app is using same navigation view.

Is it possible to show and hide navigation bar when the view is open?

***Below is the code:***

```
class CustomViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum EventDetailsStates {
        case idle
        case loading
        case eventCanceled
    }
    @Published var state = EventDetailsStates.idle
    @Published var reloadData = false
    
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name("eventCanceled"), object: nil, queue: nil, using: self.processEventCanceledNotification(_:))
    }
    
    @objc func processEventCanceledNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        // Do something
        self.reloadData = false
        self.state = .eventCanceled
     }
}

struct CustomView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CustomViewModel
    @State var showMessageView = false
    @State var hideNavBar = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch viewModel.state {
            // Some other states.

            case .eventCanceled:
            if self.showMessageView {
                MessageView().onAppear() {
                    self.hideNavBar = true
                }.onDisappear() {
                    self.hideNavBar = false
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            }
            }
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(hideNavBar).navigationBarHidden(hideNavBar).navigationBarTitle("Back")
        .onAppear() {
            if viewModel.reloadData {
                viewModel.state = .idle
            } else {
                self.showMessageView = true
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 15.0) {
                    self.showMessageView = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Adding app file's code:***

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct watchApp: App {
    @WKExtensionDelegateAdaptor(ExtensionDelegate.self) var delegate
    @SceneBuilder var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView().environmentObject(UserSettingsStore())
            }
        }

        WKNotificationScene(controller: NotificationController.self, category: "myCategory")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is message view a view that presents full screen over the current view? Or is it just a notification of sorts? Would it be possible to post the message view code so we can have a working example? I think I see the issue, but tough to be sure without fully working code.

Comment: Message view is part of the custom view. It's not full screen. It's a lot of code, so I am just providing snippets to explain my problem. Let me try to move the code to playground and provide something that you can try.

Comment: Try to move NavigationView from scene inside ContentView.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to put value of navigationBarBackButtonHidden() as true if you want to hide it, but in all your steps, the value is always false which mean Hidden = false.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @tail! I fixed the code. So initially when the view loads, I see navigation bar. When event is canceled and Message View appears, nav bar is hidden since I have hideNavBar as true. But when Message View dismisses, nav bar stays hidden across the app even though I am setting hideNavBar to false again in onDisappear(). I just have one navigation view within my app file and all the views in my app are called from Content View so entire app is using one navigation view.

Comment: Fixing the code hide's the nav bar, but doesn't show it again when I set the variable to false. So nav bar is displayed when view is opened, hides when I set the the @State var in onAppear, but does not display again when I update the variable in onDisappear().

Comment: You are telling me presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() dismisses the ContentView() and return to another view?

Comment: If you have other views before ContentView(), but it still shows nav bar after ContentView() is dismissed, then that behavior is completely correct and normal. 1 different nav bar for each different view.